# Haskell - Formatting issues

Tags: database, function, haskell, formatting, higher-order-functions

this is the current code I have to displaying a database worth of information, but when printing this out it isn't very clear to read..

```
type Title = String
type Cast = String
type Year = Int
type Fans = String

type Film = (Title, [Cast], Year, [Fans])
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
    ("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
        ("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2002, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"])]
```

when running this function:

```
displayAllFilms :: Database ->[(Title, [Cast], Year, [Fans])]
displayAllFilms [] = []
displayAllFilms ((i, j, k, l): xs)
        |l == [] = (i, j, k, []) : displayAllFilms xs
        |otherwise = (i, j, k, l) : displayAllFilms xs
```

It prints this:

[("Casino Royale",["Daniel Craig","Eva Green","Judi Dench"],2006 ["Garry","Dave","Zoe","Kevin","Emma"]),("Cowboys & Aliens",["Harrison Ford","Daniel Craig","Olivia Wilde"],2011,["Bill","Jo","Garry","Kevin","Olga","Liz"]),("Catch Me If You Can",["Leonardo DiCaprio","Tom Hanks"],2002,["Zoe","Heidi","Jo","Emma","Liz","Sam","Olga","Kevin","Tim"])]

which clearly is not readable: is there a way to make each film information (in this case) be printed on separate lines ie. utilising the /n notation?

Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
displayAllFilms :: Database -> IO ()
displayAllFilms db = mapM_ print db
```

How does this work?

- `print` is defined as

  ```
  print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
  print x = putStrLn (show x)
  ```
- How to explain `mapM_`?... You know what `map` does, yes? Given a function and a list, it applies the function to each element of the list, and gives back a list of the results.

  `map` takes a function of type `a -> b`, but `mapM_` takes a function of type `a -> IO b` (I am simplifying).  The `IO` means that the function may perform some i/o (in this case: writing to the screen, that's what `print` does).

  `mapM_` joins all those individual pieces of i/o together and ensures they occur in the right order.

Notes:

- your original `displayAllFilms` doesn't actually do anything: the output is the same as the input, the only reason anything gets printed to the screen is that you're running it from the ghci prompt
- it's spelled `\n`, not `/n` (although I am not using it explicitly because `print`/`putStrLn` add a newline at the end automatically)

Comment: Thanks for the help, for clarification, what does this part of the code do?:

displayAllFilms db = mapM_ print db